# How to concate two key in object of array? Js

Tags: javascript

I need to concate two key because i want to concate first and last name in one key username.
Example array of json

```
arr = [
 {id: 1 , first_name: Test , last_name: Test2 , city: "Berlin"  } ,
 {id: 2 , first_name: Alan, last_name: Test5 , city: "Minsk" } ,
]
```

I need create new object or same , to create anythink as

```
arr = [
 { id: 1 , first_name: Test , last_name: Test2 , city: "Berlin", username: "Test Test2" } , 
 { id: 1 , first_name: Alan, last_name: Test5 , city: "Berlin", username: "Alan Test5" } ,
]
```

Comment: have you tried anything? what does not work?

Comment: Why is `id`and `city` same on both on the output?

Comment: are `Test` and `Test2` and `Alan` and `Test5` some variables you have defined somewhere? Or should they be strings as well

Comment: I try with object.assign no work. This is only my examples of my code. Sample. Test and test 2 in same array

Comment: You can use `reduce` method. For your code, I think this would work -

    arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    currentValue.username = `${currentValue.first_name} ${currentValue.last_name};
    accumulator.push(currentValue);
    return accumulator;
    }, []);

But as I can see first_name and last_name are not of string type. Please note that this will work only when first_name and last_name are of string type.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to add the `username` property to each object in that array:

```js
let ary = [
 {id: 1 , first_name: "Test" , last_name: "Test2" , city: "Berlin"  } ,
 {id: 2 , first_name: "Alan", last_name: "Test5" , city: "Minsk" }
];

ary.forEach((obj)=>
{
  obj.username = `${obj.first_name} ${obj.last_name}`;
});

console.log(ary);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
 {id: 1 , first_name: 'Test' , last_name: 'Test2', city: "Berlin"  } ,
 {id: 2 , first_name: 'Alan', last_name: 'Test5' , city: "Minsk" } ,
]; 

arr.forEach(item => {
    item.username = `${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`; 
})

console.log(arr);
```

You can do it with a foreach loop.

Comment: Note that the provided array is not valid, i changed first and last name to be a string in order for the example to work.

Answer (score 0):

At first, the keys `first_name` and `last_name` has to be Strings, do they?

```
 let arr = [
                { id: 1, first_name: "Test", last_name: "Test2", city: "Berlin" },
                { id: 2, first_name: "Alan", last_name: "Test5", city: "Minsk" },
            ]
```

You can simply iterate through your array using `forEach` or `for` loop.

Then you can define a new key to your object.

```
 arr.forEach(element => {
    element['username'] = element.first_name + ' ' + element.last_name;
})
```

In practice it is better to check if the keys `first_name` and `last_name` exist, using `element.hasOwnProperty('last_name')`.

Comment: `element['username']`?

Comment: Adds the key ````username```` to the object. It works, try it.

Comment: yes ... it does ... so does `element.username`

Comment: @JaromandaX `element['username']` and `element.username` are both valid; personal preferences in coding style should not constitute a reason to downvote a correct answer.

Comment: There is no reason to do `element['username']` over `element.username`. Using dot is a lot cleaner and less confusing. (Most IDEs warn about unnecessary use of `[]` notation)

Comment: @secan Thank you. I personal use ````[key]```` when I am **adding a new key** (set)  to an object and use ````.key```` to **access a key** (get).

Comment: @nickzoum unless you tell them not to. It's just a preference that can be set in a linter setting. It depends on what you prefer. Both notations are perfectly valid and in some situations, one is cleaner than the other. There's no any rule.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I'm not saying that I'ts down-vote worthy, but I think unless the property is a variable, contains special characters or the object is used as a map it's more likely to confuse the reader.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new array you should use `Array#map` instead of `Array#forEach`. You should also deep-copy all the inner objects (an easy way is `Object.parse(Object.stringify(oldObject))`.

I've also assumed that the values of the `first_name`, `last_name` properties are strings (didn't have quotes on question) and that the id and city don't get merged.

```js
var arr = [{
    id: 1,
    first_name: "Test",
    last_name: "Test2",
    city: "Berlin"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first_name: "Alan",
    last_name: "Test5",
    city: "Minsk"
  },
];

var newArr = arr.map(function(item) {
  var newItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
  newItem.username = newItem.first_name + " " + newItem.last_name;
  return newItem;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: why newArr? OP want's same `arr`

Comment: @JaromandaX The question says `I need create new object` and `or same` which sounds like it's a backup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.map`

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, first_name: 'Test', last_name: 'Test2', city: 'Berlin' },
  { id: 2, first_name: 'Alan', last_name: 'Test5', city: 'Minsk' }
]

const res = arr.map(el => ({
  ...el,
  username: [el.first_name, el.last_name].join(' ')
}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @JaromandaX where exactly OP stated that he needs an in-place change?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I also don't know how he interpreted that..

Comment: `arr = existing array` .... `arr = added elements` ... see how `arr` is the same variable